# How to return JSON from a CakePHP 2.2 controller?

Tags: php, json, cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.2

I'm invoking a controller function:

```
$.get("http://localhost/universityapp/courses/listnames", function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

And in my Controller:

```
public function listnames() {
    $data = Array(
        "name" => "Sergio",
        "age" => 23
    );
    $this->set('test', $data);
    $this->render('/Elements/ajaxreturn'); // This View is declared at /Elements/ajaxreturn.ctp
}
```

And in that View:

```
<?php echo json_encode($asdf); ?>
```

However, the Action is returning the entire page including the Layout content (header, footer, navigation).

What am I missing here? How can I return just the JSON data without the Layout content?

Comment: set $this->layout = null ; in listnames

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: If you write that in as your answer I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: answer posted hope this will work for u

Comment: Be sure to `$this->response->type('json');` too 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to disable layout like this

```
$this->layout = null ;
```

Now your action will become

```
public function listnames() {
    $this->layout = null ;
    $data = Array(
        "name" => "Sergio",
        "age" => 23
    );
    $this->set('test', $data);
    $this->render('/Elements/ajaxreturn'); // This View is declared at /Elements/ajaxreturn.ctp
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Set `autoRender=false` and return `json_encode($code)`:-

```
public function returningJsonData($estado_id){
    $this->autoRender = false;

    return json_encode($this->ModelBla->find('first',array(
        'conditions'=>array('Bla.bla_child_id'=>$estado_id)
    )));
}
```

Comment: +1 The simpliest solution for this simple situation.

Answer (score 7):

Read up about [JsonView](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) on the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of the following to return json response (I've taken failure case here to return json response) :

```
public function action() {
    $this->response->body(json_encode(array(
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => 'Invalid request.'
    )));

    $this->response->send();
    $this->_stop();
}
```

**OR**

```
public function action() {
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    return json_encode(array(
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => 'Invalid request.'
    ));
}
```